# Prevent Twitter bootstrap empty <dd> filling with next <dd> value

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello CSS gurus out there,

I love the twitter bootstrap, and I am prototyping a lot of projects based on it, I encountered this problem, where if the dd tag has no HTML inside of it, another dd takes it's place, I understand why this is happening, because of the way the dl is styled it allows dd to expand to more than one row if the content needs to, i don't want to break this lovely styling, i just want to modify it so if the dd value is empty, it just won't collapse, so before i do anything crazy here like server side to hide empty values, or modifying the original behavior or even adding jQuery, i wanted to know if anyone could help, this is a picture to illustrate further what i am saying, it's RTL so the dt is on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I used this style override.

```
.dl-horizontal > dd:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

According to the [developer](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/3821#issuecomment-6561752), `<dd>` should never be empty (which I disagree).

And I think he prefer users to add `clearfix` class to the `<dd>`s that might be empty.

`<dd class="clearfix"></dd>`

**Update**

This fix is included after 3.2, see [release note](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12736).

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
<dd><%= @route.id %>&nbsp;</dd>
```

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?442551-When-dd-%28in-a-definition-list%29-is-empty-below-content-is-pulled-upwards

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting [this commit](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/37f4a25be436e8b25004d22541809032d8354600) properly, this will be default behaviour in 3.0.0. Until then you can also try adding `dl-horizontal` as an alternative to simply `clearfix`.

```
<dd class="dl-horizontal"></dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try just that:

```
dd {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I don't see why, this style applied on the element prevent the next dd to fill its space.