# Use case of HTML Definition list, and issue with bootstrap

Tags: html, web-applications, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Definition list (dl, dd, dt ) to render view page (details of an entity). Are Description list are not good for this usecase?

When use with Twitter bootstrap, when  `<dd></dd>` is empty, all of the contents shifts to top. This is undesirable to show details of an object, which may contain some properties empty.

Please see the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cPwHr/

Is this a bug? how can I prevent it.
Or should I use normal list (ul, li ..) or table.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566451/prevent-twitter-bootstrap-empty-dd-filling-with-next-dd-value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use a non-breaking space if you don't have a definition instead of leaving it empty. That way all of the css rules will still be applied as expected.

```
        <dt>Description lists</dt>
        <dd>&nbsp;</dd>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this style override:

```
.dl-horizontal > dd:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer by @gael-marziou, see this thread: [Prevent Twitter bootstrap empty <dd> filling with next <dd> value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566451/how-to-prevent-twitter-bootstrap-dds-from-going-up-if-empty)