# How to force Twitter Bootstrap .dl-horizontal DT content to wrap instead of truncate?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap has great horizontal definition list styling, but **I want the DT content to wrap, not be truncated**.

I know on their [base.css page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html) they say: *"Heads up! Horizontal description lists will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column fix text-overflow."*

Anyone know of a fix for this?

Here's the off-the-shelf bootstrap CSS I've been wrenching on with no success:

```
.dl-horizontal {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.dl-horizontal:before,
.dl-horizontal:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.dl-horizontal:after {
  clear: both;
}
.dl-horizontal dt {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  clear: left;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

My quesion here is similar to this question, if that helps:
[Prevent Twitter bootstrap empty <dd> filling with next <dd> value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566451/how-to-prevent-twitter-bootstrap-dds-from-going-up-if-empty)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can comment out `white-space: nowrap;` from `.dl-horizontal dt` block if you want to wrap content in all the dt

if you want to wrap content for a single dt then add inline `style='white-space: normal;'` to that specific dt

Answer (score 41):

add an CSS overwrite after the bootstrap CSS references

```
.dl-horizontal dt 
{
    white-space: normal;
    width: 200px; 
}
```

Comment: You can also avoid the 200px width.

Comment: You also need to adjust the `margin-left` of the corresponding `dd` element to be 20px more than the width of the `dt` element or there will be no space between them.

Answer (score 20):

I used this as I did not want to loose the line-breaking if window width becomes small:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .dl-horizontal dt {
        width:280px;
        white-space: normal;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    .dl-horizontal dd {
        margin-left:300px;
    }
}
```

The `width` and the `margin-left` are optional settings if you like to display more text in the `dt` column per line. The 20px difference is the space between the columns.

The `margin-bottom` adds a little space between the rows so they are better differentiated from each other. This is only useful if `white-space: normal;` produces a line break (do not forget that the font size can be influenced through the visitor (e.g. windows dpi setting).

[image]

small window width:
[image]

boostrap source to compare:

```
dd {
  margin-left: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.dl-horizontal dt {
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: left;
  text-align: right;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.dl-horizontal dd {
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```

Comment: I think that the margin-bottom must apply to both dt and dd,

Answer (score 5):

Give an id to your `dl`: `<dl class="dl-horizontal" id="freelance">`

Then add this to your css :

```
#freelance dt {
    overflow: visible;
    width: 170px !important;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Change width and margin if needed.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add an ID nor an !important.

Comment: This handy solution gives the opportunity to assign different widths for dt in one page.