# Empty dt in dt-horizonal not aligning with other dt elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a description list with class `.dt-horizonal` in which I make sure `dt` content doesn't truncate by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860681/2246380) post and increasing the width. It works fine but when there is an empty `dt` it doesn't work thus the alignment of next `dd`(Canada) is not right as you can see in the following output. Can someone help me fix this?

**[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7UIZeaXAUk)**

**Current output**

[image: Output]

**HTML**

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>Joe</dd>
  <dt>Age</dt>
  <dd>25</dd>
  <dt>List of Countries visited</dt>
  <dd>USA</dd>
  <dt> </dt>
  <dd>Canada</dd>
  <dt>Country of Orgin</dt>
  <dd>Brazil</dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS**

```
.dl-horizontal dt 
{
    white-space: normal;
    width: 250px; 
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a non breaking space to the dt, this will give it some content and maintain the layout. See Here : http://www.bootply.com/Vbo6v6JiaS

```html
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>Joe</dd>
  <dt>Age</dt>
  <dd>25</dd>
  <dt>List of Countries visited</dt>
  <dd>USA</dd>
  <dt>&nbsp</dt>
  <dd>Canada</dd>
  <dt>Country of Orgin</dt>
  <dd>Brazil</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2):

check out this Add this Css  since we add property to the empty content the width is maintained

```
.dl-horizontal dt:before {
  float: left;
  content: " ";
  height: 1px;
}
```