# In Bootstrap4 an empty <dd> collapses line height for corresponding <dt>

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I can see that this error has had previous chatter on

[prevent-twitter-bootstrap-empty-dd-filling-with-next-dd-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566451/prevent-twitter-bootstrap-empty-dd-filling-with-next-dd-value)

and that the developer had previously said it wasn't be fixed but...

[image: Output]

As shown empty address fields result in the margins between the labels collapsing.  It is produced via a Django template with:

```
<dl class="row">
      <dt class="col-sm-3">Address 1:</dt><dd class="col-sm-9">{{ client.address1|default_if_none:"&nbsp;" }}</dd>
      <dt class="col-sm-3">Address 2:</dt><dd class="col-sm-9">{{ client.address2|default_if_none:"&nbsp;" }}</dd>
      <dt class="col-sm-3">Town:</dt><dd class="col-sm-9">{{ client.town|default_if_none:"&nbsp;" }}</dd>
      <dt class="col-sm-3">County:</dt><dd class="col-sm-9">{{ client.county|default_if_none:"&nbsp;" }}</dd>
      <dt class="col-sm-3">Postcode:</dt><dd class="col-sm-9">{{ client.postcode|default_if_none:"&nbsp;" }}</dd>
      <dt class="col-sm-3">Telephone1:</dt><dd class="col-sm-9">{{ client.telephone1|default_if_none:"&nbsp;" }}</dd>
      <dt class="col-sm-3">Telephone2:</dt><dd class="col-sm-9">{{ client.telephone2|default_if_none:"&nbsp;" }}</dd>
      <dt class="col-sm-3">Email:</dt><dd class="col-sm-9">{{ client.email|default_if_none:"&nbsp;" }}</dd>
</dl>
```

Note: I have tried to force a space incase that would create a line.    I would have thought that the linespacing would have been set by dt which I understand should always exist and should never be empty?

Answer (score 2):

you could try this:

```
dl dd:after {
  content: "\200b";
}
```

that is a 0px width space and will not create a new line

Comment: Worked for me, as the same issue persists with Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 1):

Just set a `min-height` to every `dd` element like this:

```
dd {
 min-height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really work without a hack.  See my solution below (above).

Answer (score 1):

So I have managed to fix this although it feels like a hack and I'm surprised that Bootstrap hasn't got this under control.  Using the answer above (which I had previously tried a variation of) I have ended up with:

```
dd.col-sm-9 {
    min-height: 25px;
}
```

Because a neat dd declaration results in:

[image: Col Min-Height Over Writes DD Min Height]